# how to get bootstrap 3 responsive navbar working in IE7?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

if you open up IE7 (or IE10 in emulation mode) and visit http://getbootstrap.com, then resize your browser to less than  700px,   the top navbar menu doesn't show up until you hover over the contents.

**how could this be fixed?**

PS:  i know bootstrap isn't officially supported in IE7.   I don't mind if my site is ugly, I just want to get the functionality to work in ie7 (and right now, missing nav-bar menu's is no good!)

PPS: I know that in the usa ie7 is used less than 1%.   Here in Thailand it's more than 5%, which is why I need to support ie7 still

Answer (score 2):

I just did some tests and I think I found a way to solve the issue, it's a javascript solution that listens to the collapse `show` event and sets the `z-index` of the list items and anchor elements inside the navbar

```
$('.nav-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('li,a').css({'z-index':'auto'});
})
```

I don't know exactly what the issue is with IE7 but I think somehow setting the `z-index` forces a redraw of the elements of some sort.

Here's the test fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7jmNu/31

Answer (score 1):

You may find this IE7 for Bootstrap 3 CSS file useful.
https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

It fixes the box-sizing and adds support for the glyphicons among other fixes.